Как смоделировать Kerberos/ NTLM аутентификацию?
Надо смоделировать Kerberos или NTLM аутентификацию.
На тестовом VDS поднял Kerberos сейчас так полагаю, что надо настроить NGINX при запросе на URL делал проверку через Kerberos и отправлял на какой-нибудь маршрут и если аутентификация не пройдена, то просил бы аутентифицироваться.
В правильном ли направлении иду? Если есть у кого опыт настройки такой аутентификации - буду рад указанию пути.
